# How to get email alerts when a new file is created? Cpanel/WHM/Centos

Tags: php, centos, cpanel, whm, malware

I am trying to track some backdoors in my servers, every day new files are being created or modified, and reading the access logs I can find only the IP addresses requesting these files via web.

As I could not find anything in the FTP messages log, I am thinking how to track the file creation.

I could set a custom script in etc/profile.d which is sending me an alert everytime a user logs in via ssh.

However, I am wondering if there is any way to send a similar email alert whenever a file is created or modified, also, if it is possible to get the ip address that makes these changes.

If anybody knows how to create these alerts would be great, this would help a lot of people to fight malware being inyected on their websites.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=about&lang=en). But I generally prefer to address the disease, not the symptom. I.e., tracking that you got hacked doesn't help you not get hacked. Secure your system.

- Make sure your system is up-to-date.
- Shut down all unused/unneeded daemons.
- Run a firewall that uses the "deny all then allow what is needed" design.
- Make sure that the user running the web server process doesn't have write access to the files it serves.

Comment: Do you know how to install it via ssh? there are no instructions to install just the download file, i need to install it on Centos, thanks for your help

Comment: Oops sorry I linked the wrong thing, I meant to link [this](https://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond). That's a cron-like daemon that uses inotify to trigger scripts when files change. You should be able to install it on CentOS with `yum install incron`.

Comment: Thanks for your info sir! I will try it today and let you know how it works :D